# Type error : 'int' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python

I’ve tried many times by giving int data type, once for v and once for j, but it is not working.

```
from array import *
arr=array('i', [])
n=int(input("enter the length of the array = "))
for j in range(n):
    x=int(input("enter the value = "))
    arr.append(x)
print(arr)
s=0
v=0
while s<=n:
    v+=j[s]      #here the error is occuring
    s+=1
 return v
 print(v)
```

Comment: maybe you mean `v+=arr[s]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

j is an int carried over from your for loop. Since j is an int you are trying to access an index within j (hence why it's complaining)

You most likely intended to write arr[s] not j[s]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like v is supposed to hold the sum of the elements in the array. In that case, the line that throws the error should read:

```
v+=arr[s]
```

Instead you are trying to access an element in j, but j is an integer (from your loop above) not an array. This is why the error says that an int is not subscriptable, because you are trying to subscript an integer!